How can I retain the type hints for the validation rules like .email() and .min(6) after exporting a Zod object?
How can I retain the type hints for the validation rules like .email() and .min(6) after exporting a Zod object, so that when used in another project, these validation details are preserved?
for example, I defined a zod schema in my back-end code :
export const signInSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().email(),
    password: z.string().min(6)
})

when it is imported in a front-end project,
.email(),.min(6) validation rule information would be lost.
so the front-end user doesn't know how it looks like.

Instead of exporting the schema, you can export a function that creates the schema to retain those information:
export const createSignInSchema = () => z.object({
   email: z.string().email(),
   password: z.string().min(6)
})

// usage
const signInSchema = createSignInSchema()

